# Can't find "Jump to source" in texstudio

Tags: texstudio, forward-inverse-search

I am using TeXstudio to create pdf. After generating pdf, I can't find the "Jump to source" option to go to the relevant part of the latex file. Any solution to this problem?

Comment: right click in the internal PDF viewer. first entry in the context menu. if you were using SumatraPDF (Windows only), you can double click on the part in the PDF

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Are you using the internal PDF-viewer in TeXstudio? Isn't there a Go to source-option if you right click in the PDF?

Comment: Yes, I just installed texstudio and I guess every setting is default. And I am not fin ding Go to source option

Comment: (1) Is there a synctex fle being made when you compile? This is the communication between pdf and source. (2) do you have any non-ascii characters in the file name or folder names leading up to the tex and pdf file. This should not matter, but sometimes it does.

Comment: Yes. There is one .synctex.gz file is being made after I compile. Also my file name is pretty fine.

Comment: check the time on the synctex file matches as near as dam-it the time of the pdf (they MUST be the same name/time) however you say no right click option which usually means the corresponding named .synctex file is NOT in the same folder thus NEED to check PdfLaTeX command includes correct synctex call i.e. looks like `pdflatex.exe  -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` most common failing after that can be a space in the filename or path

Comment: @daleif 's answer saved my day. It turns out there is a non-ascii folder in my working path. rename the folder and everything went smoothly again.

Answer (score 1):

Space in the folder name or in the file name can be a factor to unavailable the option "Go to Source".